# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'subscribe' Python

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm Using `Kubuntu 13.10 64 bit` and `Python 2.7.5+` and `wxPython 2.8.12.1`. I'm trying to use the `wx.lib.pubsub` module to update `wx.Gauge` from different class (thread class). I have in my code such imports:

```
try:
    from pubsub import pub
except ImportError:
    from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
```

but  when I start my application, I'm getting the error:

```
    pub.subscribe(self.updateProgress, "update")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'subscribe'
```

What's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: `'subscribe'` doesn't seem to be a function in the `pub` module.

Take a look at `dir(pub)` and see if `'subscribe'` is in it. A simple way is to add this to your code right after your imports: `print dir(pub)` and `print 'subscribe' in dir(pub)`

Answer (score 1):

wxPython 2.8.12 contains an older version of pubsub.

In your code it is not clear which version you error on, in other words which import worked?  I guess it is the one from wx.lib which with 2.8.12 would be the old version of pubsub.

I would suggest to use either a newer version of wxPython, e.g. 3.0.2 or use the stand alone pypubsub, but if you want to stick with 2.8 then the doc shows you what needs to be done.
http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/usage/howtos/upgrade_v1tov3.html#label-upgrade-for-wx